# aggregation of data in R with assign of a dummy variable by condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset

```
 mydata=structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ad_id = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 1111L, 1111L, 11111L, 11111L, 11111L, 111L, 111L, 1111L, 
1111L, 11111L, 11111L, 11111L, 111111L, 111111L), price = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), rev = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L), data = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("01.01.2018", 
"01.02.2018", "01.03.2018", "02.03.2018"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"ad_id", "price", "rev", "data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

How can I create a dummy variable according to the following logic:
For each `id` and `ad_id` I need to aggregate by data price and rev. Each `ad_id` has a date column (data).

If for each `id` and `ad_id`for the period up to 90 days(data column -d-m-y) rev is greater than the price, then the flag is set to 1 otherwise the flag is 0.
In this reproducible example , I just take 1 id  and 4 ad_id.
In aggregated by sum form it is view

```
  id  ad_id price rev
1  1    111     2   4
2  1   1111     2   6
3  1  11111     3  12
4  1 111111     1   0
```

So for `id=1` , all `ad_id` (besides `ad_id = 111111`) satisfy rev > price, so in initial data
`ad_id = 111, 1111, 111111` must have flag = 1 and `111111` must have flag = 0.

Here is the desired output:

```
   id  ad_id price rev       data flag
1   1    111     1   2 01.01.2018    1
2   1    111     0   0 01.02.2018    1
3   1    111     1   0 01.02.2018    1
4   1    111     0   2 01.03.2018    1
5   1   1111     2   3 01.01.2018    1
6   1   1111     0   3 01.03.2018    1
7   1  11111     3   4 01.01.2018    1
8   1  11111     0   4 01.03.2018    1
9   1  11111     0   4 02.03.2018    1
10  1 111111     1   0 01.01.2018    0
11  1 111111     0   0 01.03.2018    0
```

How to perform such condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if understood you correctly, but is this what you are looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(id, ad_id) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars("price", "rev"), sum) %>% 
  mutate(flag = if_else(price > rev, 0, 1)) %>% 
  select(id, ad_id, flag) %>% 
  left_join(mydata, ., by = c("id", "ad_id"))
```

Comment: may i ask you help in this bind topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024147/restructure-the-data-with-flag-assign-in-r